# want to copy multiple files to Azure blob from Linux server

Tags: python, linux, blobstorage, azure-blob-storage

When I build the code in Linux server every time, I will get some files(with subfolders) that need to be moved to Blob storage. I don't know how to copy the files from Linux to Azure blob storage. I saw some articles in msdn blogs. I downloaded the python sdk from Github. Also I read about azure cli for linux. But I don't know how it does file copy. Could someone please tell me briefly how to copy the files from linux to Azure blob storage. Is there any simple way to do this?

Below is the url about python sdk.

http://blogs.msdn.com/b/tconte/archive/2013/04/17/how-to-interact-with-windows-azure-blob-storage-from-linux-using-python.aspx

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

If you have access to a recent Python interpreter on your Linux Server, the Azure Batch and HPC team has released a code sample with some [AzCopy-like functionality on Python called blobxfer](https://github.com/Azure/blobxfer). This allows full recursive directory ingress into Azure Storage as well as full container copy back out to local storage. [full disclosure: I'm a contributor for this code]

Answer (score 0):

I've got no idea where the Python script answers come from... I spent days chasing that dead end. 
What you need is the Azure CLI... Got it to work on both Ubuntu and Mac.
[enter link description here](https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/documentation/articles/storage-azure-cli/#create-and-manage-blobs)